# Create doughnut graph from mixed data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a dashboard graph in Excel from a single column with dates, N/A and blanks, like this:

- Date Submitted to Planning
- 20/11/2015
- 20/11/2015
- 13/11/2015
- {blank}
- N/A
- {blank}
- {blank}
- 17/11/2015
- 19/11/2015
- 22/11/2015

What I want to show is number submitted i.e. out of the 9 rows, 6 have been submitted as a doughnut graph (or similar).

I can count the rows for the total number but I'm struggling with how to count the dates and display the results in a format that doesn't just show 1 to 9.

Comment: Are the dates stored as Excel dates or text?  Is N/A text or the Not Available function (#N/A, =NA())?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a few assumptions:

- The dates are stored as dates and the day/month/year sequence is locale-based formatting.
- The N/A is actually the NA() function, and the values are displayed as #N/A.  (Actually, with the solution below, N/A can be just text.)
- That what you're looking for is something like this:

[image: donut chart]

The count of dates is done with:

```
=COUNT(A2:A11)
```

The COUNT function counts only number entries, and dates are stored as numbers.

The count of blanks is done with:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A2:A11)
```

I did this in LibreOffice Calc, so the menu selections are a little different, but the basic steps should be:

- Select the two counts
- Insert Chart
- Select Donut chart
- Pick the options you want for the display (legend, values and/or percentages, etc.)